# usb otg for motorola mb865 at&t 4.0.4

Tags: usb-on-the-go

Hi i wanna watch tv on my lapdock, this is what i have:

Motorola Lapdock 500 PRO
Motorola ATRIX 2 MB865 AT&T Android 4.0.4 +root
DVB-T Reciever for Android - CSL - mini DVB-T Stick (requirements - android 4.0 or high, dual core cpu (neon support) usb otg)
Handmade Y. USB OTG cable  (powered by wall adaptor)

After using chainfire diagnostic app for fix otg, I able to mount 2gb usb stick to phone, and can access files. means otg fix succesful and otg cable also works fine. Chainfire after check returns what is on screenshot

[image: Chainfire Diagnostics Result]

Then when i connect DVB-T Stick to phone by otg cable (else, if i connect it direct to microusb port - system not find device. possible just by otg cable) system popup message:
[image]

But after open Air Dtv (any other app which works with dvb stick simply cant find device) i get this message from app:
[image]
Reconnecting returns same error

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: after using chainfire diagnostic for fix otg, i can connect usb stick to phone, by Y. otg cable. and can access usb stick files in filemanager, delete/copy/paste etc. 
but Air Dtv programm returns "initialisation failed, reconnect dvb stick and check again" when i try to connect csl dvb-t stick to phone. 
it returns that only when i use Y. otg cable, else it not find device, if i connect it direct to microusb port
Screenshots can show usb information also, on xda board link

Comment: means i able to mount 2gb usb stick by otg cable. it works well. but same try, for connect dvb-t stick returns error

Comment: The Y cable would be the first suspect then. Since the Lapdock has its own USB ports, try connecting the DVB receiver to one of those (if the DVB receiver is USB-OTG you may need an adapter).

Comment: Also, [edit] this information into the question, so that it's easier for other visitors to see what the actual problem is. You're more likely to get relevant answers that way.

Comment: Y cable works cause i can mount 2gb usb stick by it, and able to access files.
dvb-t stick package contain microusb(female)-usb(male) adapter, i try connect dvb stick to lapdock using this adapter - device not found. looks like external power needed. just want first finish it succesful on phone, then try on lapdock